# How do I create a SQL server database which is not Sql server compact?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have Visual Studio 2010, Sql Server 2008, Sql Management Studio and pretty much everything installed. 
I can create a local database with Sql Server Compact and Windows authentication just fine. Now I'm a little perplexed, because I still have no idea how all of this works. I didn't use any connection strings, passwords or anything. While coding, I can clearly see that the DataContext class in C# when using LINQ to SQL needs a connection string. How can I test this on my own pc? Is it unreasonable that I want to test this kind of stuff throughly while not currently having hosted services on the Internet yet? And often times, I don't have so much access to the server when using shared hosting, so I can't learn very fast and not fully.

When trying to connect to different services through SQL management studio and Windows authentication and my local pc, I just get a connection error.
    Error Number: 2
    Severity: 20
    State: 0
I don't think that the database engine is the appropiate service to connect to anyway based on what I read, I just thought that you would like to know what I tried.
I checked, and sqlservr.exe is running in the processes in the task manager. Also SQL Server VSS writer.

Basically, I would like to learn how SQl Server databases work. The books, wikipedia and msdn on this topic just enumerate a lot of cryptic services like the database engine, analytical services etc...
I can't find any basic information on how to actally create, connect and program with a real database on my own pc. I'm not even sure whether I'm supposed to work like this?

I read that Sql server compact only supports databases up to 2mb.
Is it not possible for me to work with "the real thing" on my local pc?

I'm very very new to all this, and I'm not getting anywhere with databases...
Thanks for any help!

See:  no option for a full sql database.

[image: No option for full Sql database?]

Server seems to run, but why does it say Server express? I'm sure I have the full one.
[image]

Comment: Compact and Express can handle up to 4 gig and not 2mb.

Comment: Ah good, here it says even 10gb. http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Visual Studio generally installs a SQL Server instance on your local machine.

It is acceptable to work with "the real thing" on localhost, since when changing server, only the connection string has to change.

You will have to install the right version of [SQL Server Management Studio Express (SSMSE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx) for your version of SQL Server so that you can start it, authenticate and work with SQL Server.

You may also connect to your SQL Server using the `Server Explorer` windows from within Visual Studio. Menu `View|Server Explorer`, or else `[CTRL]+[W]`, `[L]` to view it. Then, you may connect to a data server from this window using the connection buttons on top of it.

1. Click **View|Server Explorer**, to view it;
2. Server Explorer, click **"Connect"** button located on top;
3. Choose a data source dialog, Data Source, click **Microsoft SQL Server**;
4. Data Provider, select **.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server**, click `[Continue]`;
5. Add a connection dialog, Server name, select the server you want to connect to (your `[local machine name]\SQLEXPRESS` might appear, or something alike);
6. Server connection, choose **Windows Authentication**;
7. Database connection, select the database you want to connect to, and click `[Test Connection]`;
8. If the test succeeds, click `[OK]`, and you're done!

**Disclaimer**

> The names of menus or window title may differ a bit, but you should get it done anyway. That is because I have off my head translated from French to English what it actually says in French, working with a French Visual Studio.

**EDIT #1**

After having taken an eye out your screenshot, I would simply say that you only have to select `Database Engine` to connect to your SQL Server instance, by selecting the right server on which you wish to work.

The full database option you're looking for is **Database Engine** which designates a full SQL Server.

The others are for the different services such as:

1. **SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)**;
2. **SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)**;
3. **SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS)**.

Feel free to ask further assistance as needed. =)

Comment: I find it much better to install a SQL Server in a virtual machine.  1)it is on "another" machine, more like the real case.  2) It won't slow down your machine when you don't need it.

Comment: @Will I already have SQL Server Management Studio (the full version, not express. I got it from Dreamspark) There is no option to create a full sql server database. I can only select database engine, analytic services etc, and sql server compact when trying to connect in the object browser. I'll add a picture.

Comment: @Blub: Great! Then you may eitehr use it, or go through Visual Studio. I didn't know you already had it. Anyway! I hope my answer helps. =)

Comment: @iDevelop: Agreed! And, it doesn't mean that every one has the skill to do so as a developer. That said, I totally agree with a virtual machine, and still there is no wrong of working locally either, as the OP asks.

Comment: @Will: I'm trying to connect, but it says that the service isn't running: here is the exact error I get: http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2 I can instead use the visual studio "connect to database file", this is the only way it works. But this way I don't have to use any connection strings and no server. It's a little strange. The sql server configuration is a confusing, it says the express server is running.

Comment: I added a picture of the configuration.

Comment: I looked into "Registered servers" window in the management studio, and it says that there aren't any local servers. hm

Comment: I'm not totally sure of what I'm going to say, and deserves to be tried out anyway. Start your `SQL Server Browser`, that is, the service which allows to browse for servers through the network (and locally). Try this, and it might work. On the other hand, I see that you have SQLEXPRESS installed. De you remember the name of the instance you chose during the installation process? This might be the cause. What is the name of the server you try to connect to? Is it **[localMachineName]** or **[localMachineName]\SQLEXPRESS**?

Comment: @Will: Thank you, it worked. Apparently I needed to append \SQLEXPRESS. The reason is not really clear, I have found this article on msdn (even with my browser history, it took me 5min to find it again...) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166996.aspx "If the Database Engine is a named instance, the Server name box should also contain the instance name in the format <computer_name>\<instance_name>." Strange, because the default sql instance should not have any instance name according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174516(SQL.80).aspx.

Comment: Still strange that it is called SQLExpress. I was under the impression that I had a full installation.

Comment: That must be why we had a hard time connection to it. That is when it's installed that you may change it. I know of no other way, though there be must be. I'm glad I could help! Besides, I prefer named instance since it allows you to have multiple database engines services to run all at once. We mostly don't need to, but it can be seen like it.